# How to join servername, database name and database size in a single select query in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to join server name ,database name and database size in a single select query.

```
Server Name Database Name   Database Size in MB Report_Time  
SYBD012     CBA_ATM         3856.81 MB          08-02-17 16:40   
SYBD012     CBA_CM_PPP      398203.94 MB        08-02-17 16:40  
SYBD012     CBA_CM_TTT      38436.81 MB         08-02-17 16:40  
SYBD012     CM_C01          32764.00 MB         08-02-17 16:40  
SYBD012     ECMStaging      1985.25 MB          08-02-17 16:40  
SYBD012     FNMPDataWarehou 601.50 MB           08-02-17 16:40
```

I tried this query but still I didn't able to take servername from sysservers.

```
select name,sum(size)/512 MB from sysusages u ,sysdatabases d where d.dbid=u.dbid
```

Comment: Please format for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot join with `sysservers`. It has no meaning.
`sysservers` holds the servers on which this current server can connect and execute remote procedures.

If you'd like to get your current server name, You can get it with: `select @@servername`

In any case, the correct way to get all your databases size is (assuming your page size is 2):

```
select
    sum(size) * 2 / 1024 db_sizeMB,
    db_name(dbid) database_name
from
    master.dbo.sysusages u
group by
    dbid
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly you will have to use three part name in the query. Something like this
select  from model.dbo.sysusages mds
where mds. = ''